# Can't remove element from the array

Tags: array, delete

Does anyone can explain me why the pid is not deleted from my pids list ?
The for loop still occure the same number of time each time I go in this
The var i is equal of the number of pids. So the loop while should stop when all pid will be finished but it doesn't! I still have the pid inside the array pids

This command seems to be not working : pids=("${pids[@]/$pid}")
Is there anything wrong with it ? I want to remove the $pid from the pids array.

```
 while [ $i != 0 ]
                do
                        for pid in "${pids[@]}"
                        do
                                if [ -z "$(ps -p $pid -o pid=)" ]
                                then
                                        echo "i = $i ,pid $pid is finished" | tee -a $LOGFILE
                                        ((i--))
                                        pids=("${pids[@]/$pid}")
                                        echo
                                else
                                        echo "i = $i ,pid $pid is not finished"
                                fi
                        done
                        sleep 4
                        clear
                done
```

Comment: which language/shell is this?

Comment: `for pid in "${pids[@]}"` expands `"${pids[@]}"` into a static list and then iterates over it.  Since the list is static, changing the contents of the `$pid` array inside the loop does not change the items that the loop sees.  I suggest either building a new array with the elements you want to keep from the `$pid` array, or use the `for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 ))` loop to iterate over each indexed element of the `$pid` array, but if you're deleting elements, iterate **backward** from the highest to the lowest index.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you do `("${pids[@]/$pid}")`, it substitutes the `$pid` item in the array with an empty string (""). So the item isn't actually **removed** from the array, it's just **replaced** with an empty string item.

I'm guessing that after some pids gets "removed" from the array, the next cycle of `for pid in "${pids[@]}"`, the following line will produce an error, since at least **some** of the $pid variables will be empty:

```
if [ -z "$(ps -p $pid -o pid=)" ]
```

This `ps`  probably throws some error to stderr, but the output (STDOUT) of the command would be empty, so it will decrement `$i` by 1, and eventually `$i` will probably drop below zero, and since it will never be 0, the loop will never stop.

since all of the items of the in the array are numbers, you fix this by removing the quotes from the following line:

```
pids=("${pids[@]/$pid}")
```

So instead it would be:

```
pids=(${pids[@]/$pid})
```

Without the quotes the empty elements are removed from the array.

Here's a short example:

```bash
$ array=( 1 2 3 )

$ echo "${array[@]/1}"
 2 3
# Notice that the first item is replaced with an empty string

$ echo ${array[@]/1}
2 3
# Without the quotes, the empty string is removed
```

Notice this only works because the items in the array are numbers. It will not work if the array contains strings and spaces.

In addition, this method only substitutes **substrings** (and not necessarily whole array items), so for instance, if `pids=( "1", "123" )`, and `pid=1`, the result of `(${pids[@]/1})` would be `( "23" )` (removing the "1" from "123", and only the "23" will remain.

See the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16861932/8529284) for additional details and a method to remove an item from any array regardless of the content of the array.

### Disclaimer:

This answer only explains why your script didn't work as expected. My suggestion will probably make your script work, but it's not written in the most optimal way. There are many changes that could make the script cleaner and more efficient, but I'm not going into it in this answer.